# Send cross border payments without local deposit anchor

Tags: anchor, network, token-wallet, path-payment

Is it possible to allow my users of my wallet app to send payments to another country without a local deposit anchor but by funding their accounts using an exchange like binance then making a path payment to the receiving anchor to be sent to a bank account?

Answer (score 0):

Technically it does not matter how an account is funded and once it is funded, it can make path payments.
Practically you will most likely run into anti money laundering legal issues if you commercially top up other peoples accounts through your own without regulation.

Comment: So it would be better to allow them to fund their own accounts individually?

Comment: My users are businesses, so I thought they would fund their own stellar accounts and adhere to local regulations themselves, and once their account is fund, use the wallet with their accounts, my understanding is that businesses would be better able to meet regulations requirements than ordinary users, that's why I chose businesses and institutions